# Dim dash lights

Tags: lights

I have a Vauxhall corsa, suddenly when I turn my headlights on my dashboard lights go very dim, it does not happen when turning any other instruments on, IE Radio, heater fan etc, the car does not struggle in idle and starts every time without problems, could this be a battery issue, any advice please

Comment: Welcome to the site. What year is your vehicle? Is this a recent problem? What have you attempted to resolve it?

Comment: Why do you think this is a sudden problem, as it is factory functionality on many cars?

Answer (score 2):

This is normal in many cars, as soon as you turn on your headlights the dashboard lights are dimmed. Many car manufacturers make the assumption that its probably be dark outside when you turn on your headlights, so the dashboard lights should be dimmed. Nothing in your story leads me to believe that you have a battery issue.

Comment: This is not an answer, rather a comment. Please avoid using the answer area to ask clarifying questions.

Comment: @CharlieRB i've clarified my answer

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply, but this NEVER used to happen before and when I mean dim it's practically none existent, I follow and understand your comment but this isn't the case

Comment: Like @CharlieRB asked before: What year is your vehicle? And do you have a dimmer wheel or knob for the dashboard lighting?

Comment: I agree with @MadMarky, it's probably meant to do that, you've likely turned down your dash lights using the adjuster which is right next to the headlight switch.